# Integrate Laravel into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel

The idea is to use WordPress as the front-end using Yootheme and Laravel as the back-end. I am able to do this to a certain extent using [wl-bootstrap](https://github.com/lehoangduc/wl-bootstrap).

However I am unable to get access to my laravel controllers in my wordpress views.

Any feedback on how to do this would be much appreciated.

I would also like to know if you believe this setup is a good idea or not?

**Edit: The client wants to be able to do updates via WordPress and use [Yootheme](https://yootheme.com/) for the front end**

Edit: Thank you for all your answers. I ended up creating a Laravel API to query data in WordPress.

Comment: If you are suing laravel as back-end then what is the meaning of wrodpress? Just think about it

Comment: Hello Maxime, this question belongs to another stackexchange network site and also has been asked before. Try this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239117/wp-and-laravel-integration-updated

Comment: The meaning of wordpress is to create the templates

Comment: Laravel Provide Blade template for front-end you can use.

Comment: The other way around seems to make more sense: WordPress as backend, using the WP API to provide data to the Laravel views. So no, I don't think it is a good idea - the templating system of WordPress is not very advanced in my opinion and often results in pretty messy code in your themes. Just look at the default themes that come with every installation. Laravel uses a MVC approach which should be fine if you don't have a complex business logic. You could use your models to retrieve data from your WordPress backend.

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  It would be like a customer asking a mechanic to use a Maserati body but all Aston Martin internals.  Is it possible?  Maybe.  Is it practical or worth the hassle?  No.

Comment: Wordpress has an inbuilt backend. why not just used that. You can even customize it

Answer (score 1):

TBH I can't really see why you would need Laravel to do a Wordpress site from the question, so this answer is a punt at best.

Laravel has many components from Symfony, there is actually a Symfony/Wordpress hybrid at https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle however my experience tells me that if you need something more than Wordpress can provide, Wordpress isn't the right choice at all (right tool for the job and all that).

---

**Integrate Wordpress into Laravel**

If you add `require( 'path/to/wp-blog-header.php' );` to the top of the Laravel `public/index.php`, you should have access to the Wordpress functionality in Laravel, then you could do something like...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    protected $posts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = get_posts($args);
    }



    public function index($cat_slug)
    {
        return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $this->posts]);
    }
}
```

---

**Add a wordpress blog without integrating**

If you want to do something like have a blog on a Laravel site, you could just add a directory `public/blog/` and put the Wordpress installation in there.

---

**Sharing database**

If you want them to share a database, make sure you create a model class containing the tables and columns.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'wp_posts';

    protected $fillable = ['post_title', 'post_content', 'etc'];

}
```

Then you can reference them in your controllers or other libraries.

Comment: To your initial why: WordPress is the most used CMS in the world, it is easy to use (basics) and also many people can operate with it already without lecture, what it lacks is the performance and some built-in functionalities Laravel (or other framework) has - it is highly possible WP will target those things in future, but right know the base performance is incomparable.

Answer (score 1):

The smartest way to create Wordpress Laravel integration is with WordPressPete. Imagine powering the front end of your website in WordPress while managing content, payments, subscriptions, advanced tools, and custom dashboard in the powerful MVC framework Laravel 5. Picture being able to deploy this robust development environment in just a few clicks:

Check this tutorial:

https://wordpresspete.com/2018/11/03/create-a-wordpress-laravel-integration-with-wordpresspete-part-one/

WordPressPete is a local and production server environment that can be installed in macOS and Linux with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat old post but came across this as I am also interested in using Laravel functionality in a Wordpress site. It absolutely makes sense and there is no reason why the other way around is only sensible approach.

So yeah, Laravel components available in Wordpress backend is pretty awesome.

The way I am currently doing it is installing Laravel components that I want via composer in top level directory. So I now have a vendors folder, where each component has a composer.json with autolad info. So in my functions.php, I just call

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

I just did this for the Pusher php library that is awesome for real time notification functionality and often used with Laravel. So I am using Pusher on my WordPress site using same techniques as used on my Laravel site. Just that I have to write the callbacks in line with WordPress, like authorizing a private Pusher channel.

So in your case, not very different conceptually. Just require autoload, then figure out what classes you need.

You could create a folder like `App/Http/Controllers/Api` and set up a restAPI approach to pull data as needed from WordPress, where in WordPress you define a Custom RestAPI Endpoint to your Laravel endpoint.

Jut read that you ended up writing a Laravel API, so maybe this is what you ended up doing? Curious, are you using Laravel Routes? That is something I would really be interested in figuring out - that is, how to use Laravel routes in way that don't interfere with Wordpress, so that I could have site.net/laravelroute and it would bypass all wordpress checks, routing.