# Laravel and Wordpress routes and directories

Tags: laravel, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a new Laravel + Wordpress project and I would like these to be the URLs of each part of the site:

- example.com: App made with Laravel
- example.com/blog: Wordpress blog
- example.com/store: Online store made with WooCommerce (Wordpress)
- example.com/whatever: Other pages of the Laravel app

And finally, I would like both blog and store to be the same instance of Wordpress avoiding having two separated Wordpress installations. How should I deal with directories and htaccess configurations in order to get what I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check this articles
https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-laravel/

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/integrate-laravel-and-wordpress/

https://vegibit.com/how-to-add-a-wordpress-blog-to-your-laravel-application/

https://medium.com/m/global-identity?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.devgenius.io%2Fwhy-when-and-how-to-develop-wordpress-with-laravel-features-live-examples-f7958cf1b7ea

https://medium.com/@Madgeek_in/how-to-install-a-wordpress-blog-to-your-laravel-web-application-24e79036ce77

and this question
[Integrate Laravel into Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366578/integrate-laravel-into-wordpress)

and this package
https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).